# How to convert numpy array to a Zarr array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, data-conversion, zarr

Suppose I have a converted a simple to column dataframe to a numpy array:

```
gdf.head()
>>>

     rid    rast
0      1    01000001000761C3ECF420013F0761C3ECF42001BF7172...
1      2    01000001000761C3ECF420013F0761C3ECF42001BF64BF...
2      3    01000001000761C3ECF420013F0761C3ECF42001BF560C...
3      4    01000001000761C3ECF420013F0761C3ECF42001BF7F25...
4      5    01000001000761C3ECF420013F0761C3ECF42001BF7172...

raster_np = gdf.to_numpy()
raster_np[0][0]
>>> array([1, '01000001000761C3E.........], dtype=object))
```

I've been tasked with converting the numpy array to a `Zarr` file format (because of the size of the `rast` values and the size of the dataframe, chunking and compression might be necessary and the new .zarr files could be utilized better on an S3/cloud storage environment, I assume). I created a simple `Zarr` array like so:

```
 z_test = z.zeros(shape=(10000, 2), chunks=(10000, 2))
 z_test
 >>> <zarr.core.Array (10000, 2) float64>
```

Now, how do I get the data in `raster_np` into `z_test` and retain the `Zarr` attributes? Simply using `z_test = raster_np` obviously doesn't work. Perhaps there is something I am misunderstanding about `Zarr`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since your initial array is of mixed type (object) you need to create the zarr array with the correct data type, and encode the data. You can use the JSON encoder from `numcodecs`

```python
import numcodecs

z_test = zarr.zeros(shape=(10000, 2), dtype=object, object_codec=numcodecs.JSON())
z_test[:] = raster_np
```

You will however have better performance if you store the `rid` and `raster` column as separate arrays with `int` and `str` datatypes respectively, or convert the hex to another basis.